# MIssing class "au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.BeanToCsv" from OpenCSV from maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, opencsv

I used the "http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#maven-integration" maven dependency for opencsv as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am unable to find the class `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.BeanToCsv` from the resolved dependency. Refer here:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/bean/BeanToCsv.html

I even tried 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 versions. Unable to find version 2.4 on maven repo.

Can anybody confirm if this class belogns to new 2.4 snapshot api? Can't see any 'Since' annotation from the javadocs.

Comment: The docs are for version 2.4-SNAPSHOT. The current version on sourceforge is 3.1 (and there is 3.1 on Maven Central, too). However, I would suggest to download the library from sourceforge and add it to your local Maven repository manually. I don't think that the developer published it to Maven Central.

Comment: 3.1? Can you point me to the url please? I can't find 3.1 on the link here: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Here it is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that the sourceforge is indeed pointing to 3.1 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs delivered with version 2.0 state that there is no `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.BeanToCsv` class. This is the class summary of the package `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean`:

- ColumnPositionMappingStrategy
- CsvToBean
- HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy
- HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy

Additionally version 2.4-SNAPSHOT is not the current version, but version 3.1. I think the developer does not maintain the Maven repository anymore. You have two options:

1. Download the library from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) and install it to your local Maven repository (or include it in your project in a different way).
2. Add a [3.1 dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.opencsv|opencsv|3.1|bundle) from Maven Central to your pom.

I would prefer option 1, because I don't know who uploaded the library to Maven Central.